# Unlock DataStage job

Tags: datastage

i am planning disconnect the user session(to unlock job) through a Unix script , provided a session id as input.

Here is the manual procedure i found from IBM website.

IBM procedure starts

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21439971

In web console check active sessions and if job is listed disconnect session.

To view all active sessions:

In the Web console, click the Administration tab.
In the Navigation pane, select Session Management > Active Sessions

The Active Sessions pane shows the users that are currently connected to the server.

IBM procedure ends

i found that there will be a file(some audit file in server) which stores logtime,userid and session id.

i want to disconnect based on available inputs(session id,user id).

xmeta db contains session information.

http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?p=294127&sid=a71eb0861ea8061b8e04ab09a93bac03

table name **xmeta.xmetalockinfo**

if i delete the row corresponding to session ,is it will remove lock or do i need to do any other Synchronization activity ?

how the web console disconnecting in background.

Comment: What version are you using?